# Why does React add class is="null"?

Tags: reactjs

A beginner question: I am rendering a collection of items with React render function and I noticed that React automatically adds attribute `is="null"` to each rendered DOM element.

Why is React doing that? Is the key applied correctly or not? The respective code is:

```
export default class ItemList extends Component {
  render() {
    let { items } = this.props
    items = items.map((item) => {
      return <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{item.attributes.name}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In the DOM, each `div` and `h3` has attribute `is="null"`

```
<div is="null">
  <h3 is="null">Item 1</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise the spelling of "corrently or not? The respenctive" as the meaning of your question is less than optimal without that.

Comment: And by `class` do you mean an attribute? It'd help if you can paste the react generated markup here as well.

Comment: @HazardouS yes, it is an attribute, not class, of course

Answer (score 0):

This is Firefox issue and its already in pipeline

https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/is-null-attribute-on-every-tag/4032/7

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6896

Comment: Please provide an explanation rather then just links to other articles.